# Typescript generics return type

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and I am trying to wrap my head around how generics work. I am wondering why the following code doesn't fly:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    let num: number = 2;
    return num;
}

let output = identity<number>(1);
```

I get the error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'. If the input to the function is a number, does this not mean that the return type of number should work as well, since we are saying that T is of type number?

Comment: `T` is not going to *necessarily* be a number. You might have, for example `identity<string>("hello")` in which case `return num` would be wrong. You've put nothing to ensure that `T` is in any way related to `number`, so TS will fail compiling this as it cannot guarantee the compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You have to treat `T` like any type in existence. Your function head says: I want an argument of type T and return something of type T.

Your code however always returns a `number`, which does not have to be `T`. In your example call it is, but you could call it with `identity<string>("test")` and expect a string to come back, but it would still be a `number`. Thus the confict.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at the type signature of your identity function.

```js
function identity<T>(arg: T)
```

What we are saying here is that this function acceps an argument of type `T` (which we are not specifying in advance, it could be anything), and it return a value of type `T`.

Given that there is no information whatsoever about `T`, the only the function can return a value of such type is to reuse the provided argument. In other words, there is exactly one and only one possible implementation of the identity function - the one that returns its argument.

```js
function identity<T>(arg: T) { return arg }
```

The error message is telling you exactly this: `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'`, which is true because `T` is, well, generic :)

Answer (score 0):

Short story , you should correct your function like this:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    let num: T = arg;
    return num;
}

let output = identity<number>(1)


console.log(output);
```